# If statement to check if a table exists in database given form field as search criteria?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I have quickly written what I would like the code to do and the basics of what it is:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
session.clear()
form = AddCardForm(request.form)

if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
    card_name = form.card_name.data
    card_set = form.card_set.data
    card_number = form.card_number.data

    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

    card_name_result = cur.execute("SELECT card_name FROM %s WHERE card_name = %s", [card_set, card_name])

    if card_set == **TABLE_NAME** & card_name_result == 1:
        cur.execute(
            "UPDATE card_quantity in table +1"
        )

return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

Is there a possible way set the TABLE_NAME to be a table within the database?

So basically run the if statement if what the user enters in the card_set form field is a named table?

Comment: You can't use parameters for table and column names, only expressions.

Comment: It's generally poor design if you need to specify the table name dynamically like this. Dynamic data should be in contents, not table and column names.

Comment: You should have one big table with all cards, and `card_set` should be a column, not different tables for each set.

Comment: @Barmar yeah it's looking like that's the best way to do it! Thanks :)